# Не работает код по выдачи ролей в Discord?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord import client
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
 await ctx.send('pong')

@client.command()
async def addrole(ctx,role: discord.role, user: discord.member):
 if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
  await user.add_role(role)
  await ctx.send(f"Роль выдана! {role.mention} to {user.mention}.")

@client.command()
async def removerole(ctx, role: discord.role, user: discord.member):
 if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
  await user.remove_role(role)
  await ctx.send(f"Роль убрана! {role.mention} to {user.mention}.")


client.run('Token')
```

При попытки ввести !addrole @user @role допустим - вылезает вот это:

```
Ignoring exception in command addrole:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Program_Files_x86\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 467, in _actual_conversion
    return converter(argument)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Program_Files_x86\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "E:\Program_Files_x86\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "E:\Program_Files_x86\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "E:\Program_Files_x86\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "E:\Program_Files_x86\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 552, in transform
    return await self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "E:\Program_Files_x86\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 505, in do_conversion
    return await self._actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "E:\Program_Files_x86\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 476, in _actual_conversion
    raise BadArgument('Converting to "{}" failed for parameter "{}".'.format(name, param.name)) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "discord.role" failed for parameter "role".
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы пишете "При попытки ввести `!addrole @user @role`" появляется ошибка.

Суть в том, что у вас функция принимает аргументы в порядке: `роль`, `пользователь`, а вы отправляете ей `пользователь`, `роль`

**Вот, посмотрите сами:**

```
async def addrole(ctx,role: discord.role, user: discord.member):
                      ^^^                 ^^^^
                      роль            пользователь
```

Так что попробуйте вызывать `!addrole @role @user`, только не с восклицательного знака, а со слеша (`/`), потому что он у вас указан в префиксе.

---

Также для работы с участниками сервера было бы неплохо выдать намерения (`intents`).

**Замените строку:**

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')
```

**На эту:**

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents = discord.Intents.all())
```